# Drupal Development : Should I use the built in content type or create my own content type?

Tags: drupal, dictionary, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to create an online Arabic-Hebrew Dictionary for one of my clients and this is my first experience in Drupal Module Development. If I were to create the Dictionary in custom PHP and MySQL, I would create a number of database tables and do my queries accordingly.

I know that there is a built-in content type in Drupal 7, should I use it or create my own content type, If I should create my own content type, how can I do it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in content type will give you a Title and a Body, you can also use taxonomies in order to get more specific queries.

Creating your own content type will depend on your site structure. If the above is sufficient, simply use  or modify the built in content types, otherwise create your own.

My advice would be for you to experiment with Drupal, watch various tutorials, then decide on the structure that would be best fit your requirements.

Your question is very vague, there are a lot of resources out there for Drupal beginners, you'll get a more detailed answer by checking tutorials first.

Comment: You didn't get me right ..... In other words, If you were to create a dictionary in Drupal which has a custom search on the words/verbs , would you begin by adding a new content type from "#overlay=admin/structure/types/add" and benefit from the built in content type system and then query the content type from a module, or creating the content type (Entity) in your module.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it depends. It generally is better to build upon the existing content types as much as you can. But if you determine that it would be too awkward/inconvenient to build upon the pre-existing content types in order to get the best solution to your problem, then you should programmatically create your own content type in your module.

Whichever path you choose, make sure that you properly document your content type structure, so that whenever you or someone else has to use that module, they will know exactly what each field is being used for, any dependencies, etc.